# Installing the Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Based on recommendations on SO for the Zend framework, I'm planning to use it for a client's project.

However, my client requires that the project should run on both Yahoo! Small Business and GoDaddy  hosting.

Can the Zend framework be installed on these types of hosting, which are neither VPS nor dedicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can run PHP code on the server and the PHP version and installed extensions satisfy the [minimum requirements](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/requirements.introduction.html), you can use the Zend framework. You don't really need to *install* Zend, just as you don't need to install any PHP app. The files just need to be present in some `include`-able directory.

Comment: Thanks, deceze. "The files just need to be present in some include-able directory." <-- Can that be done on a shared/reseller hosting?

Comment: @Jon "Include-able directory" == any directory you can read and `include` files from. The framework is just a bunch of `.php` files, just like the ones you need to copy to your server anyway. So, yes.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need to install it. Just copy it to some directory within your application, include [Zend's Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) class and use it to load rest of the classes you need.

Comment: Thanks, Ondrej. So does that mean I won't even need to put it in an "include-able" directory?

Comment: Well, of course you will need to do that. But include-able directory is really almost any part of your application.